Need a small validation regarding bound in Foundry
Example test:
contract CounterTest is Test {
    function setUp() public {}

    function testFuzz_A(uint a ) public {
        a = bound(a, 5, 10);
    }

    function testFuzz_B(uint256 x) public {
        x = bound(x, 1, 4);
        testFuzz_A(x);
    }
}

When we call testFuzz_A with the value of x, does the bound statement for x get ignored, because testFuzz_A is accepting uints greater than 4?
So no matter what we define as the bound range of the parent function, the testFuzz_A will only receive the values within its bound range.
Is my understanding correct?
Here is the trace:


Yes, the testFuzz_A will only receive the values within its bound range, because the values of x that it's receiving from the parent function (i.e., testFuzz_B) don't lie within the bound range of a, as the bound ranges of x and a are (1, 4) and (5, 10) respectively, that are mutually exclusive sets.
But, if you slightly overlap them, like if you define the bound of x as bound(x, 5, 8), then whatever the value of x is, will be the value of a.
function testFuzz_A(uint256 a) public pure {
    a = bound(a, 5, 10);
    console.log("A: ", a);
}

function testFuzz_B(uint256 x) public pure {
    x = bound(x, 5, 8);
    console.log("X: ", x);
    testFuzz_A(x);
}




